# Calling a function with an argument from another function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

How do I call a function with an argument from another function? Here is my function:

```
def check(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print('even')
        return 'even'
    elif x % 2 != 0:
        print('odd')
        return 'odd'
```

Now I would like to create a second function which would print something depending on what check function returns and still be able to set a value for 'x' argument.

Comment: Can you show us *precisely* what you want your second function to do? Pseudo-code is better than a description.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are looking for. Why you don't set the 'x' value first then call your two functions ?

Comment: you need to declare x as a global variable. then any function can say global x and use the x which is global now, thus can set value to it.

Comment: @koksalb a global variable is rarely the correct answer. This is not one of those rare cases.

Comment: In what way are you not able to write it?

Comment: You should have just searched a little bit instead of asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

you can call check like this:

```
print(check(x))
```

and define the function:

```
def check(x):
    return 'odd' if x%2 else 'even'
```

Comment: can you set the question as answered please?

Answer (score 0):

```
def check(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print('even')
        return 'even'
    elif x % 2 != 0:
        print('odd')
        return 'odd'

def print_foo(x):
    test = check(x)
    if test == 'odd':
        print('odd from print foo')
    elif test == 'even':
        print('even from print_foo')
```

Comment: @PeterWood Sorry - I have not switched from "C++" mode. Edited